# Populate PDF as a pop-up window, jsf web application

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I am new to web programming.
I have a web application in JSF2.0 and i need help.

The application needs a pdf to be embedded in a pop-up window (with out disturbing the current page). The logic to generate is handled in a java bean, as a byte array (using Apache FOP).

Along with the pdf, there has to be a "Print" and a "Close" buttons on the top (just above the pdf). The "Print" capabilities handle the print capabilities.

Please help

Comment: The solution is simple. Hire someone to do it :P.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a very good way to achieve this, is to use some jQuery (or wathever) client library to display PDF docs in browser. You can find some useful jQuery plugins here: http://www.jquery4u.com/javascript/javascriptjquery-pdf-viewer-plugins/